# numpy does not get installed giving an error in Preparing metadata

Tags: python, numpy

```
> pip3 install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.26.2.tar.gz (15.7 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 2
  ╰─> [68 lines of output]
      + C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\python.exe C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2312zix2\numpy_c94715e07a8a4d408715aefe578da10b\vendored-meson\meson\meson.py setup C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2312zix2\numpy_c94715e07a8a4d408715aefe578da10b C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2312zix2\numpy_c94715e07a8a4d408715aefe578da10b\.mesonpy-piiirdj4\build -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --native-file=C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2312zix2\numpy_c94715e07a8a4d408715aefe578da10b\.mesonpy-piiirdj4\build\meson-python-native-file.ini
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2312zix2\numpy_c94715e07a8a4d408715aefe578da10b\vendored-meson\meson\mesonbuild\mesonmain.py", line 194, in run
          return options.run_func(options)
        File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2312zix2\numpy_c94715e07a8a4d408715aefe578da10b\vendored-meson\meson\mesonbuild\msetup.py", line 358, in run
          app.generate()
        File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2312zix2\numpy_c94715e07a8a4d408715aefe578da10b\vendored-meson\meson\mesonbuild\msetup.py", line 183, in generate
          return self._generate(env, capture, vslite_ctx)
        File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2312zix2\numpy_c94715e07a8a4d408715aefe578da10b\vendored-meson\meson\mesonbuild\msetup.py", line 228, in _generate
          intr.run()
        File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2312zix2\numpy_c94715e07a8a4d408715aefe578da10b\vendored-meson\meson\mesonbuild\interpreter\interpreter.py", line 3002, in run
          super().run()
        File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2312zix2\numpy_c94715e07a8a4d408715aefe578da10b\vendored-meson\meson\mesonbuild\interpreterbase\interpreterbase.py", line 164, in run
          self.evaluate_codeblock(self.ast, start=1)
        File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2312zix2\numpy_c94715e07a8a4d408715aefe578da10b\vendored-meson\meson\mesonbuild\interpreterbase\interpreterbase.py", line 190, in evaluate_codeblock
          raise e
        File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2312zix2\numpy_c94715e07a8a4d408715aefe578da10b\vendored-meson\meson\mesonbuild\interpreterbase\interpreterbase.py", line 182, in evaluate_codeblock
          self.evaluate_statement(cur)
        File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2312zix2\numpy_c94715e07a8a4d408715aefe578da10b\vendored-meson\meson\mesonbuild\interpreterbase\interpreterbase.py", line 198, in evaluate_statement
          self.assignment(cur)
        File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2312zix2\numpy_c94715e07a8a4d408715aefe578da10b\vendored-meson\meson\mesonbuild\interpreterbase\interpreterbase.py", line 635, in assignment
          value = self.evaluate_statement(node.value)
        File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2312zix2\numpy_c94715e07a8a4d408715aefe578da10b\vendored-meson\meson\mesonbuild\interpreterbase\interpreterbase.py", line 200, in evaluate_statement
          return self.method_call(cur)
        File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2312zix2\numpy_c94715e07a8a4d408715aefe578da10b\vendored-meson\meson\mesonbuild\interpreterbase\interpreterbase.py", line 550, in method_call
          res = obj.method_call(method_name, args, kwargs)
        File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2312zix2\numpy_c94715e07a8a4d408715aefe578da10b\vendored-meson\meson\mesonbuild\interpreterbase\baseobjects.py", line 94, in method_call
          return method(args, kwargs)
        File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2312zix2\numpy_c94715e07a8a4d408715aefe578da10b\vendored-meson\meson\mesonbuild\interpreterbase\decorators.py", line 109, in wrapped
          ret = f(*wrapped_args, **wrapped_kwargs)
        File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2312zix2\numpy_c94715e07a8a4d408715aefe578da10b\vendored-meson\meson\mesonbuild\interpreterbase\decorators.py", line 127, in wrapped
          return f(*wrapped_args, **wrapped_kwargs)
        File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2312zix2\numpy_c94715e07a8a4d408715aefe578da10b\vendored-meson\meson\mesonbuild\interpreterbase\decorators.py", line 826, in wrapped
          return f(*wrapped_args, **wrapped_kwargs)
        File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2312zix2\numpy_c94715e07a8a4d408715aefe578da10b\vendored-meson\meson\mesonbuild\interpreterbase\decorators.py", line 64, in wrapped
          return f(*wrapped_args, **wrapped_kwargs)
        File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2312zix2\numpy_c94715e07a8a4d408715aefe578da10b\vendored-meson\meson\mesonbuild\modules\python.py", line 204, in dependency_method
          dep = self._dependency_method_impl(kwargs)
        File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2312zix2\numpy_c94715e07a8a4d408715aefe578da10b\vendored-meson\meson\mesonbuild\modules\python.py", line 189, in _dependency_method_impl
          dep = find_external_dependency('python', self.interpreter.environment, new_kwargs, candidates)
        File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2312zix2\numpy_c94715e07a8a4d408715aefe578da10b\vendored-meson\meson\mesonbuild\dependencies\detect.py", line 124, in find_external_dependency
          d = c()
        File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2312zix2\numpy_c94715e07a8a4d408715aefe578da10b\vendored-meson\meson\mesonbuild\dependencies\python.py", line 224, in __init__
          if mesonlib.is_windows() and self.get_windows_python_arch().endswith('64') and mesonlib.version_compare(self.version, '<3.12'):
      AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'endswith'
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.2.99
      Source dir: C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2312zix2\numpy_c94715e07a8a4d408715aefe578da10b
      Build dir: C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2312zix2\numpy_c94715e07a8a4d408715aefe578da10b\.mesonpy-piiirdj4\build
      Build type: native build
      Project name: NumPy
      Project version: 1.26.2
      C compiler for the host machine: cc (gcc 12.2.0 "cc (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project) 12.2.0")
      C linker for the host machine: cc ld.bfd 2.39
      C++ compiler for the host machine: c++ (gcc 12.2.0 "c++ (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project) 12.2.0")
      C++ linker for the host machine: c++ ld.bfd 2.39
      Cython compiler for the host machine: cython (cython 3.0.6)
      Host machine cpu family: x86_64
      Host machine cpu: x86_64
      Program python found: YES (C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\python.exe)
      Did not find pkg-config by name 'pkg-config'
      Found Pkg-config: NO
      Unknown Windows Python platform 'mingw_x86_64'
      Unknown Windows Python platform 'mingw_x86_64'

      ..\..\meson.build:41:12: ERROR: Unhandled python exception

          This is a Meson bug and should be reported!
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

It gives me the above error while installing numpy, how can I resolve it?

Comment: How did you install python and are you using a virtual environment? Seems like it might be an issue with mingw: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/22023

Comment: yeah I resolved it. you were right the problem was with mingw. There is python.exe and pip.exe files inside the mingw/bin and when I run pip command command prompts use that pip.exe. So I added my installed python folder and script folder where the pip is to the environmental variables and reordered them above the mingw path. Then it worked. Thank you!